# C++ substring check

Tags: c++11

I'm given two strings s1, s2 and an integer i. I want to check if the substring of s1 starting at index i of the same length as s2 equals s2. I know this is trivial to implement with a little loop, but I would prefer to use a library method if it exists.

Comment: [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) might be a good start?

Comment: **I want to check if the substring of s1 starting at index s1 of the same length as s2 equals s2**. what???

Comment: @ethang It's fairly obvious that it's index `i`. Basically `s1.substr(i, s2.size()) == s2`, but ideally without temporaries ;-)

Comment: why is everyone making things so complicated?  what's wrong with just: *s1.compare(i,s2.length(),s2)==0*

Comment: @ethang is that guaranteed to play well if `s1` isn't long enough? If so, why don't you just post the answer and get lot's of upvotes?

Comment: @stefan, if s1 is shorter than i, you get an exception.  if s1 is shorter than i+s2.length(), it returns false.

Comment: Exception? Or Undefined Behavior?

Comment: @MSalters,  out_of_range exception. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: you can always short circuit with *(i<(s1.length()))&&* to avoid exception

Comment: @ethang: I see. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare listed no explicit exception but it's thrown from the ctor of temporary.

Comment: @MSalters, cppreference is screwed up.  *May throw the exceptions thrown by the corresponding basic_string constructors* makes absolutely no sense.  None of the functions invoke the constructor.  out_of_range is thrown here.  Try it for yourself.

Comment: @ethang: Check the note on the second overload. The behavior is specified _as if_ substrings are constructed. And that involves constructors.

Comment: @MSalters, *as if* is not the same as is.  Documentation to the interface shouldn't assume a specific implementation, and that's why cppreference is screwed up.

Comment: @ethang: Have you read the Standard? It uses the same pattern. This doesn't assume a specific implementation, the opposite in fact. It highlights that the actual implementation may very well differ, as long as the visible behavior (i.e. the exception thrown) is the same.

Comment: @MSalters, yea the standard does that too for brevity, which is another reason why cppreference is screwed up (because it adds nothing new). well for one, as documentation, it's difficult to follow (just as you didn't see the out_of_range).  for two, it specifies an suggested implementation.

Comment: Interesting to see how many comments this would get. I was assuming that there would pretty much be a single call subroutine for something this simple, but couldn't find it. @stefan's proposal is what I first tried, but realized it would have this behavior and I wanted to avoid putting around it a length check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, here's an in place solution using string::compare (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)

```
    s1.compare(i,s2.length(),s2)==0
```

Which would throw an std::out_of_range exception if (i>=s1.length()).  Otherwise, it works.  To avoid the out_of_range exception, just add something to short circuit the compare:

```
    (i<s1.length()) && (s1.compare(i,s2.length(),s2)==0)
```

Comment: This is probably good enough. It's probably as efficient as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using `std::equal` with a check of proper size first. That way it directly works for vectors as well. The check of sizes is necessary to avoid invalid iterators:

```
if ( i + s2.size() > s1.size() )
{
    return false;
}
auto s1beg = s1.cbegin() + i;
auto s1end = s1.cbegin() + i + s2.size();
return std::equal(s1beg, s1end, s2.cbegin());
```

If you want to support any ranges, use `std::advance` to create the start and end iterator:

```
auto s1beg = s1.cbegin();
std::advance(s1beg, i);
auto s2end = s1beg;
std::advance(s2beg, s2.size());
```

Here's a [demo for both strings and a list.](http://ideone.com/qOd3M4) A further design decision may allow different container types as well.

Comment: I don't think the `std::advance` version is as generic as you think it is: single-pass ranges (i.e. forward iterators) can be advanced but when you do so you lose the ability to check the values you advanced over. A for-loop with additional checks for end iterators does support any range.

Comment: @MSalters According to cppreference and my interpretation of it, this show work perfectly fine with forward iterators: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator Can you give an example in which this fails?

Comment: Sorry, my bad: input iterators not forward iterators. Imagine an iterator over `std::cin`. If you advance that, you ignore input which you cannot latter un-ignore.

Comment: MSalters, well yes, input iterators are special. But having the template of a container type (see the demo) makes usage with input iterators fairly unlikely. I think it's sufficiently generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool is_sub_string=i <= s1.size() && s1.substr(i, s2.size()) == s2;
```

Comment: This creates a temporary string. Is that really what you want to do when you're just observing two strings?